# Rx-java pass by reference or pass by value?

Tags: android, rx-java

In java methods [everything is passed-by-value so i can change the object attributes passed to the method and expect that the original object attributes are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/3248593). but in this method i get different result:

I have this method:

```
public Observable<Menu> makeMenu(Menu menu, NumberSettingChanges.MenuChanges changes) {
    // Start flow with added and edited extensions
    return Observable.from(changes.added.entrySet())
            .mergeWith(Observable.from(changes.edited.entrySet()))
                    //Upload announcement voices or do nothing if extension is not an announcement
            .flatMap(e -> {
                        if (AppTypeContract.APP_TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT.equals(e.getValue().type)) {
                            return mMediaManager.uploadAsync(e.getValue().config.localPrompt)
                                    .doOnNext(response -> {
                                        //Update extension prompt with the storage path.
                                        menu.config.extensions.get(e.getKey()).config.prompt = response.mPath;
                                        menu.config.extensions.get(e.getKey()).config.localPrompt = "";
                                    })
                                    .flatMap(response -> Observable.just(e));
                        } else {
                            return Observable.just(e);
                        }
                    }
            )
}
```

and i manipulate menu attributes in the flatmap:

```
menu.config.extensions.get(e.getKey()).config.localPrompt = "";
```

I call the method in the same class:

```
public Observable<NumberSetting> saveSettings(NumberSetting o, NumberSetting n) {
    NumberSettingChanges changes = compareNumberSetting(o, n);

    return makeMenu(n.day, changes.day)
            .mergeWith(makeMenu(n.night, changes.night));
    }
```

and finally:

```
saveSettings(ns, mNumberSettingNew).subscribe();
```

What i expect is that the `mNumberSettingNew.menu.config.extensions.get(e.getKey()).config.prompt` is changed but no change is happening after this call and the `mNumberSettingNew` has no change at all.

Note that i am sure that changing prompt line is done in the debug.

Comment: you are saying everything is passed-by-value and again your are saying you can manipulate the object attrbiutes adn changes will be reflected in the actual object. This is not true. Objects are passed as a reference.

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/3248593 if i change the attribute of my object the original object is changed, right?

Comment: yes that is right because they are passed as a reference. By in the question you have posted everything is passed-by-value.

Comment: And that value is a reference to the same object and i do not make a new one, right?

Comment: Guys, in java evething passes by values. But when you pass object, you are really not pass object. You pass value of reference to object. In other words this is copy of original reference. Thereof you can change object attributes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I could explain Java's parameter semantics any better than (or even half as good as) the link you referenced in your first paragraph so I won't try. The main point is: Everything in Java is passed by value (i. e. copied) but with objects what is copied is not the *object itself but the reference to the object*. So in other words *the reference is passed by value*.

So with respect to your particular problem: Yes, if you pass a reference to a mutable object to some rx-java code that reference will point to the same instance of the object. If you mutate the instance then the caller code will also be able to see the changes because they were made on the *same instance*. That's because rx-java is still only Java and cannot change the language semantics on that level.

Without seeing the whole code I am unsure what could be the problem here... When are you checking whether `mNumberSettingsNew` actually has the changes you were making in your `doOnNext`? If you check that immediately after `saveSettings(ns, mNumberSettingNew).subscribe();` your `uploadAsync` may not have returned yet. You could try adding an actual `Subscriber` in your `subscribe` and check the result there.

On a more general note, I think you should try to avoid side-effects like this as much as you can when using rx-java. Your case - taking an input object, applying a set of (possibly asynchronous) changes to that object, and waiting for the changed output object - is a bit tricky, but I think it could be done with `scan`. Maybe something vaguely like this:

```
Observable.from(changes.added.entrySet())
    .mergeWith(Observable.from(changes.edited.entrySet()))
    .scan(menuBeforeAnyChanges, new Func2<Menu, Change, Menu>() {

        public Menu call(final Menu previousVersionOfTheMenu, final Change nextChange) {
            // since I don't know of a version of scan that can return 
            // an Observable you would I think you would have to adapt
            // your code in here to be fully synchronous - but of
            // course the scan itself could run asynchronously
            final newVersionOfTheMenu = previousVersionOfTheMenu.applyChange(nextChange);
            return newVersionOfTheMenu;
        }
     )
```

This would take the original Version of the menu, consecutively apply all the changes from `added` and `edited` and /emit/ every updated version of menu. So you would not have any side effects but simply subscribe to that observable with a `Subscriber<Menu>` and then take the `last()` Menu and that would be the one with all changes applied.

**EDIT**: Oh, I just saw that there is another method called `reduce` that does just that: first `scan` and then `last` or `takeLast`.